# Submitting to a journal with only LaTeX, how to include transparent images and bitmaps?

Tags: graphics, pdf, eps, png

The LaTeX [submission process](http://jcp.peerx-press.org/html/aip_instructions.html#latex) to the journal JCP involves

1. Bundling all the bibliographies into a single file and embdeeding that into the source
2. No external libraries
3. Compile with `latex` not `pdflatex`
4. Only `.eps` images allowed, a consequence of `latex`

As such, I'm stuck trying to place my nice images that are either `.pdf` or `.png` into their submission form. The non-transparent pdfs I can convert to eps, but the transparent ones choke. In addition, I'm not sure how to convert a png to an eps - everything I've tried on the (unix) command line looses significant quality. The frustrating thing is you can watch the logs and in the end they convert the latex `dvi` to a `pdf`. Any suggestions on how to get my images into a latex source without losing quality?

Comment: Try to import the `pdf/png` figure on Inkscape, for example, and export (save as) as `eps`.

Comment: @Sigur This works well for the PNG's, and does not cause the quality to degrade nor the size to explode (as `convert` does). However, 1] it is not automated and 2] for `pdf` files it converts them to `ps` on import which garbles the fonts somewhere (embedding or not).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about graphics conversions, not TeX.